# Laptop delaying specific 1 website only ?

Tags: website, delay

this is a very very expert question that is remain unanswered in years either a bug or anything I don't know but somebody have to solve it - lets work together and find a solution, let me state the problem.

everything was running smooth and fine, but suddenly one day I wasn't able to access my site properly "by means of properly it was loading then after every 5 to 10 sec it show me error of timed out for 5 to 10 second then again start working for 5 to 10 second. First I thought my site is down - contacted the support they said everything seems to be fine - to challenge their opinion, I ask my friend to open my site and surf it he lives next to my house and using the same internet provider I use ... after 10 mins I got a call from him - he said everything is fine -then I used a proxy server and everything was running smooth - I thought it must be something with my router I start my brothers laptop and personal PC to check things amazingly they are also working fine with my site but on my laptop it persist. I tried every thing but nothing helped me I read question answer the only solution is to re install windows. and i remember the same problem was with a game site back in 3 years - and the only solution i end up re installing windows.

before answering please read what I already tried --

I am using windows XP service pack 3 - Core 2 due - 2.2ghz 1gb ram every other site and every application is running smooth and fine my internet is pretty fast.

-I have tried the host file solution there is nothing written expect the demo instruction. -I have cloned the mac address of router. -I have directly connect my laptop with out router. -I have used the system restore point. -I have cleared my cache and everything - even re-installed the whole browser. -I have checked in every single browser even in the text browser. -I have contacted my my Host Provider no IP issue. -Changed my computer IP. -Contacted my ISP no problem there as well. - used DNS Flush - no firewall restriction - firewall is off. - no antivirus restriction - even uninstalled the anti virus to just make sure. - deleted everything on domain to check if it works then -tracert route always working -ping is always alive. -website is running smooth from around the world even from my PC.

any other thing i have to try ?

Comment: What do you mean by "my site"? Do you mean a site hosted on your own network?

Comment: no they are hosted on godaddy server and Working fine every where. expect my laptop